# Catch photo upload in WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, imagepicker

I would like to intercept photo uploading which was started from javascript from site loaded with WKWebview.
Normally I would implement:

```
`func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {`
```

but since photo uploading does not comes from me I am not able to set delegate.

I had one try with overriding UIImagePickerController and setting delegate in viewDidLoad but it seems to not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {

     open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = picker
     }
}
```

where picker has to implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate